# Handle scroll down inside the webpage

Tags: javascript, selenium

Can some one help to handle the scroll down inside the web page..(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF5iG.jpg)

I have tried the code by using EventFiringWebDriver to scrolldown but it's showing the error like cannot set property and the above image is the sample of my webpage

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling should be doable manually.

Try to do this on the website before trying to code it:Position yourself on the last element visible, press down arrow to see if you find yourself on the next one. If this works you should do the following loop:

1 Position yourself on the last element visible.

2 Use send keys to send down arrow 8 times if I am counting right. This should give you 8 new elements.

3 Get those new elements on selenium.

4 Go to 1.